# After Effects Expression - How to access a layer within a comp within a comp?

Tags: javascript, jsx, after-effects

I want to create a picture gallery. A video on gets spawned at center and moves to the outer edge of the composition over a given time. Additionally it fades in and out and gets bigger towards the end of the anim segment.
On top, at the end (or start) of each cycle I want to turn a different video layer on.

The structure is a comp with several layered videos (feed_comp). That's inside another comp which loops the thing (feed_loop_comp). The looped comp is placed on the main timeline (main_comp).

All expressions are added to the "feed_loop_comp" in the "main_comp". So an expression for transform, opacity and scale.

**How and where can I add an expression to solo a random layer in the "feed_comp"?**

I tried to add the code to a random parameter like "anchor", but it seems those slots only take or output the specific var needed for them. Like "anchor" only wants to see coordinates.

I also tried to add a null and add the expression there.. but there is no "general" slot to add a code snippet not related to the slot (eg. anchor)

?? So again. Where to add such code?
?? And how to navigate to a layer within a comp, within a comp?
Like thisLayer.layer(1).layer("randomPick").solo = true;

Just for reference - this is the expression I added to the "position":

```
segDur = 5;
minVal_s = [0.49*thisComp.width, 0.49*thisComp.height];
maxVal_s = [0.51*thisComp.width, 0.51*thisComp.height];
minVal_e = [-0.1*thisComp.width, -0.1*thisComp.height];
maxVal_e = [1.1*thisComp.width, 1.1*thisComp.height];

seed = Math.floor(time/segDur);
segStart = seed*segDur;
seedRandom(seed,true);
startVal =  random(minVal_s,maxVal_s);
seedRandom(seed+1,true);
endVal = random(minVal_e,maxVal_e);
ease(time,segStart,segStart + segDur, startVal, endVal);
```

and this was my try to do the randomization:

```
if (time == segStart) {
    randLayer = Math.ceil(generateRandomNumber() * layer_count);
    activeLayer = thisLayer.layer(1).layer(randLayer);
    activeLayer.solo = true;
}
```